# Monitor my jsp-servlet application through JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I am new to JMX and I want to manage (or monitor) my jsp-servlet application, with lots of servlets and JSP files running in Tomcat.

I made a simple demo application which was given by the Oracle tutorial but it is just for one interface and its implementations so how can I monitor my whole jsp-servlet application by JMX?

I want to Monitor three things

1. Memory
2. JVM
3. Thread

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use `Jconsole` to monitor remote as well as local applications.
For that you have to enable `Jmx` on your tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own monitoring tool by using JMX or try [jeeObserver](http://www.jeeobserver.com/) for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using **jvisualvm**.
VisualVM provides detailed information about Java applications while they are running on the Java Virutal Machine (JVM).
The 3 things that you need to monitor can be done here.
See more at: http://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html#sthash.NVjHO3bo.dpuf